# Source missing function body, how is it compiling?

Tags: go, compiler-errors, compilation, function-declaration

In the Go lang source code, I see a function declared without any body. 
https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/math/log10.go#L9

```go
func Log10(x float64) float64
```

But when I do the same it gives me an error: missing function body for __

https://play.golang.org/p/Ncp-0-8vHB

How is this working in the Go source code? I mean how is the math package compiling? Is this source file just for documentation purposes?

It seems like Log10 is a public/exposed version of log10, but there is no "getter" convention or anything like that in the language, so where is the body of Log10 declared???

Comment: The 20'th duplicate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is defined in assembly for various architectures in the `*.s` files located in the same package.

Per [the spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Function_declarations):

> A function declaration may omit the body. Such a declaration provides the signature for a function implemented outside Go, such as an assembly routine.

Comment: I see. Then is there some special flag/option used during `go build` to specify that the body is declared in assembly? Or how is it "mapped"?

Comment: It's mapped by name: notice that the names defined in assembly match those stubbed in the .go files.

Comment: ok, didn't know about go asm, thanks